Delta of European Call using Malliavin Calculus
I am trying to implement the calculation of the Delta under the Heston model using Malliavin Calculus in python. According to "Malliavin Calculus in Finance" by Álos, the Malliavin delta is given as
$$\Delta = \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_0} = \frac{e^{-rT}}{T\sqrt{1-\rho^2}S_0}\mathbb{E}\left[f(S_T)\int_0^T\frac{dB_s}{\sigma_s}\right],$$
where $\rho$ is the correlation between the price- and volatility-process, $T$ is the maturity time of the contract and $B$ is the Brownian motion driving the volatility-process.
The evaluate the integral numerically, I use the following approximation:
$$\int_0^T\frac{dB_s}{\sigma_s}=\sum_{i=0}^N \frac{\sqrt{\Delta t}}{\sigma_t}Z_t,$$
where $N$ is the number of steps, $\Delta t=T/N$ and $Z_t$ is are idd random variables taken from $N(0,1)$ at each time step.
My current attempt for a European call can be found below:
def heston_sim(S0, v0, rho, kappa, theta, xi, T, N, M):
"""
Inputs:
 - S0, v0: initial parameters for asset and variance
 - rho   : correlation between asset returns and variance
 - kappa : rate of mean reversion in variance process
 - theta : long-term mean of variance process
 - xi : vol of vol / volatility of variance process
 - T     : time of simulation
 - N     : number of time steps
 - M     : number of scenarios / simulations

Outputs:
- asset prices over time (numpy array)
- variance over time (numpy array)
"""

dt = T/N
mu = np.array([0,0])

S = np.full(shape = (N+1, M), fill_value = S0)
v = np.full(shape = (N+1, M), fill_value = v0)

Z = np.zeros((N+1, M, 2))

#While performing the monte carlo simulation, we want to obtain the malliavin weights simultaneously
delta_weights = np.zeros(M)

for i in range(1,N+1):
    Z1, Z2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, M), np.random.normal(0, 1, M)
    Z_v = Z1
    Z_s = rho * Z1 + np.sqrt(1 - rho**2) * Z2
    Z[i-1, :, 0] = Z_s
    Z[i-1, :, 1] = Z_v
    S[i] = S[i-1] * np.exp((r - 0.5 * v[i-1]) * dt + np.sqrt(v[i-1] * dt) * Z[i-1,:,0])
    v[i] = np.abs(v[i-1] + kappa * (theta - v[i-1]) * dt + xi * np.sqrt(v[i-1] * dt) * Z[i-1,:,1])
    
    delta_weights += np.array(Z[i-1,:,1]*np.sqrt(dt/v[i-1])) / (T * S0 * np.sqrt(1 - rho**2))

    ST = S[-1]
    delta_mall = np.exp(-r*T) * np.average(np.multiply(np.maximum(ST-S0, 0), delta_weights))    
return S, v, delta_mall

This code should calculate both the price and volatility process and simultaneously evaluate the integral numerically. However, when reducing the Heston model to the constant volatility case and comparing the delta with the expected Black-Scholes result, the error is significant.
Is there something wrong with my approximation of the integral or my code? Any help and/or tips are much appreciated!

Let's compare the exact Malliavin formula for the delta:
$$ \Delta = \frac{e^{-rT}}{T\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}S_0}\mathbb{E}\Bigl[f(S_T)\int_0^T \frac{dB_s}{\sigma_s}\Bigr] $$
to its numerical approximation of the integral:
$$ \int_0^T \frac{dB_s}{\sigma_s} \approx \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{\sqrt{\Delta t}}{\sigma_{t_i}}Z_{t_i} $$
where $\sigma_{t_i} = \sqrt{v(t_i)}$ and $B_s$ drives the volatility process. In the Heston model, the stochastic differential equations (SDEs) are:
$$ dv_t = \kappa(\theta - v_t)dt + \xi\sqrt{v_t}dW^2_t $$
and
$$ dS_t = S_t(rdt + \sqrt{v_t}\rho dW^2_t + \sqrt{v_t}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}dW^1_t). $$
Here, $W^2$ drives the variance $v_t$, so $B_s$ must correspond to $W^2$.
Your code typically sets Zv = Z1, Zs = rho * Z1 + sqrt(1-rho**2) * Z2, then uses the following discrete-time approximations:
$$ v[i] = v[i-1] + \kappa(\theta - v[i-1])dt + \xi\sqrt{v[i-1]dt}Zv $$
$$ S[i] = S[i-1]\exp\Bigl((r - \frac12 v[i-1])dt + \sqrt{v[i-1]dt}Zs\Bigr) $$
Since Zv drives the variance $v$, for the integral $\int_{0}^{T} \frac{1}{\sigma_s}dB_s$, ensure $B_s$ matches the Brownian motion carried by Zv. In your code, this corresponds to the first component of the random variable Z, giving:
$$ \int_0^T \frac{dW^2_s}{\sqrt{v_s}} \approx \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{\sqrt{\Delta t}}{\sqrt{v[i]}} Zv[i] $$
The expression delta_weights += Z[i-1, :, 1] $\frac{\sqrt{\Delta t}}{\sqrt{v[i-1]}}$ requires the correct volatility driver (Zv), while the factor $\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$ belongs with the stock's Brownian motion (Zs). Using absolute values in v[i] = |v[i-1] + kappa * (theta - v[i-1]) * dt + xi * sqrt(v[i-1] * dt) * Zv| can bias the variance $v_t$. Additionally, the choice between using a payoff like $\max(S_T - S_0, 0)$ or a different strike price $K$ will affect comparisons.
The numerical formula for the delta is approximated by:
$$ \Delta \approx \frac{e^{-rT}}{T\sqrt{1 - \rho^2}S_0}\frac1M \sum_{m=1}^{M} \Bigl[\text{payoff}(S_T^{(m)}) \times \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{\sqrt{\Delta t}}{\sqrt{v^{(m)}[i]}}Zv^{(m)}[i]\Bigr] $$
For Black-Scholes limit testing, set $\kappa=0$, $\theta=v_0$, and $\xi=0$ to achieve constant variance $v(t)=v_0$. Also set $\rho=0$ (or any value since it's irrelevant in this case). Ensure that the Brownian motion used to calculate the Malliavin weights in delta_weights matches the Brownian motion that would drive $dv_t$, which is Zv. This procedure should result in an agreement with the Black-Scholes delta.
